# Cannot reference other modeling project

Tags: visual-studio, reference, modeling

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that contains two modeling projects.  One project contains a library of classes that I wish to reference in the other.  I added the library project to the client's Layer References, but I don't seem to be able to reference the library's classes.

Specifically, I would like to use a class in the library as the type of a method parameter in the client.  However, the classes in the library do not appear in the dropdown when choosing a parameter type.

Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to reference the library in some other way?

On a related note: How do I reference types from the .Net Framework?  I found some old posts for how to do this with VS 2010, but those menu options are not in VS 2015.  Some posts seem to say that referencing the .Net Framework is no longer possible, but that doesn't seem right.